# How to change the Title of my Enterprise Wiki & how to show the rating starts

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-logo

I have the following two problems inside my Enterprise Wiki Template:-

1. I am unable to change the title of the Page from “SharePoint” to “My company name”.
2. Also the rating stats will not show up when the page load first time,, and I have to refresh the page to display them.

I have marked the two problems in red as shown in the below image:-

[image]

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SharePoint text highlighted is not the "Title of the Page" but rather the branding text for the whole Web Application.

To change just the text you can use PowerShell (but note that this will, as said, impact the whole Web Application):

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity "http://URLtoPage"
$webApp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = '<div class="ms-core-brandingText">YOUR TEXT</div>'
$webApp.Update()
```

As you can see, you ar passing in the complete `<div>` element for the text, so you could for example render a picture, create a link, add some css class or what ever you need.

By using for example some jQuery you could make the text change based on the current page.

[Here is a great link for modifying stuff in the Suite Bar](http://spandps.com/2013/04/20/mastering-the-sharepoint-2013-suite-bar/) (the blue bar on top of the page)

Comment: Great! I recommend you to add issue #2 as a separate question to make sure it receives attention :)