# SharePoint 2013 Star Ratings Star Images Not Showing

Tags: wiki, content-rating

I've got a newly provisioned SharePoint 2013 farm in which I have an Enterprise Wiki to be used to provide help to end-users.

When I navigate to a wiki site or page the star images don't show up.  I get the alt text.  It doesn't appear to matter whether the content has been rated yet or not.

Similar to this part 2 of this question: [How to change the Title of my Enterprise Wiki & how to show the rating starts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70019/how-to-change-the-title-of-my-enterprise-wiki-how-to-show-the-rating-starts)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can force IE9 mode on your SharePoint 2013 installation by adding the X_UA-Compatible tag to your master page as:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

This tag should be placed directly under the head tag and the default master page has the tag with IE=10 defined.

[Source](http://blog.lekman.com/2013/01/ie10-fails-to-render-ratings-in.html)

Comment: If you work with Microsoft technologies for a while then things like those really stop being so surprising after a while... IE11 also had problems with SharePoint, which had to be manually added to a Compatibility Mode list to properly render things such as a calendar view.